# How to avoid repetitive naming in python packages?

Tags: python, module, package

Say I am building a python project that models bananas, how would I structure it? I usually start with

```
mkdir bananas
```

then I code in bananas.py which is file until I start adding README, LICENSE, CONTRIBUTORS, and more and the python files are just lost in meta files. Then I do the same again

```
mkdir bananas
mv *.py* bananas
```

in order to have the actual code separated from the meta. Now I have a double, repetitive dir structure,

```
$ ls /path/to/bananas
README
LICENSE
CONTRIBUTORS
bananas/banana.py
```

So this ends up in

```
bananas/bananas/banana.py
```

This just feels wrong to me. The code I touch most is hidden away too far. Also I hate imports like

```
from bananas.bananas import Banana
```

I just want to do

```
from bananas import Banana
```

Any thoughts? What am I missing? I quote [HGP](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/):

> Repetitive paths are confusing for both your tools and your
>   developers. Unnecessary nesting doesn’t help anybody (unless they’re
>   nostalgic for monolithic SVN repos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this is unavoidable. Just look at the datetime module of the standard lib.

```
datetime.datetime datetime.datetime.today().date()
```

You can do relative imports. A file in bananas only has to do

```
from bananas import Banana  # or
from .bananas import Banana
```

Which is recommended anyway to make your module reusable by making it movable m)

Some folks import the module, not the class

```
from bananas import bananas as bananaModule
bananaModule.banana()
```

You could also give your project a fancy codename so it becomes:

```
from fancyish.bananas import bananas as bananaModule
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you know about a hack that uses init to store Banana?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't see any problem with structuring it like that, and it's what I've done in my own projects. It seems to be the recommended approach according to a few online guides I've tried following.

For instance, from [Open Sourcing a Python Project the Right Way](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/) the author defines the structure of an example project:

```
$ pwd
~/code/sandman
$ tree
.
|- LICENSE
|- README.md
|- TODO.md
|- docs
|   |-- conf.py
|   |-- generated
|   |-- index.rst
|   |-- installation.rst
|   |-- modules.rst
|   |-- quickstart.rst
|   |-- sandman.rst
|- requirements.txt
|- sandman
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- exception.py
|   |-- model.py
|   |-- sandman.py
|   |-- test
|       |-- models.py
|       |-- test_sandman.py
|- setup.py
```

So in this case you'd end up with a path like `sandman/sandman/sandman.py`.